# Deriving std::hash::Hash for enums

Tags: enums, rust

I'm having problems auto-deriving the `Hash` trait for an enum. My code specifies `Hash` as a trait for my enum, but the compiler tells me I'm not implementing it.

Here's the code:

```
use std::collections::HashSet;
use std::hash::Hash;

#[derive(Hash, Eq, PartialEq, Debug, Clone)]
enum DishCategory {
    Green,
    Carb,
    Protein,
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq, Eq, Hash)]
struct Dish {
    name: String,
    ingredients: Vec<String>,
    dish_type: HashSet<DishCategory>,
}
```

The error given by the compiler:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::collections::HashSet<DishCategory>: std::hash::Hash` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:15:5
   |
15 |     dish_type: HashSet<DishCategory>,
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::hash::Hash` is not implemented for `std::collections::HashSet<DishCategory>`
   |
   = note: required by `std::hash::Hash::hash`
```

I'm using Rust 1.19.0 (`0ade33941 2017-07-17`)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You cannot implement `Hash` for **`Dish`** because `Dish` has a `HashSet`, which itself never implements `Hash` regardless of what type it contains.